# Find similar values in multiple columns, sum and get range

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to solve this issue for a week but couldn't find the right way to do so.

[image]

As shown on the image above, I have a list of data. Column A is a group identifier, Column B is sub group and then we have percentages in Column C.

My goal is to find A: 1117, loop in 'theSameTitle', sum up percentages and if they exceed 10%, I'll display total percentage or some text in column D. The thing is that I also want to merge corresponding rows along the "summed block". In case of 1117:theSametitle I would merge 3 rows in column D. This "merge" is for reporting purposes.

So far I can find 1117:theSameTitle and sum it, but can't figure out how to detect which rows are involved to merge them. Here's the code I came up with:

```
Sub determinePercentages()

     ' Select cell A1, *first line of data*.
      Range("A1").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         ' Insert your code here.

         nextCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
         'nextCell2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value

         If Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row) > 0.1 Then
            'MsgBox (Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value)
            Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "YES"
         End If

         'If ActiveCell & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) <> nextCell & nextCell2 Then
           curSumIfs = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C:C"), Range("A:A"), ActiveCell.Value, Range("B:B"), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value)
           If curSumIfs >= 0.1 Then
              ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value = curSumIfs
           End If
         'End If

         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop

End Sub
```

I'm also fairly new to VBA and Excel. I don't know how efficient my code is. Maybe there's a much better way to implement it.

I need your help :)

Comment: You have a couple undeclared variables in your code.

Comment: One approach is to "merge" as you go, comparing the current row (both columns A and B) to the previous row, and if the same merging the current row with the previous row's [`MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) in column D. As far as the current implementation, see [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and try to avoid the use of `ActiveCell` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to "merge" as you go, comparing the current row (both columns A and B) to the previous row, and if the same then merging the current row with the previous row's [`MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) in column D.

Code demonstrating just the merge (I'll leave you to incorporate the "YES" and "Sumifs")

```
Sub DeterminePercentages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                If .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
                    .Range(.Cells(i, 4), .Cells(i - 1, 4).MergeArea).Merge
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]